# Export all subscribers

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have nearly 85000 subscribers in All subscriber list, but when I try to export only two records get exported in csv file.

Comment: How are you trying to export the Subscribers? Using an automation with a query activity, by clicking on export in Email Studio or completely different?

Comment: By clicking on export in Email Studio. I think you cannot use query against All Subscribers

Answer (score 2):

We are having an issue where half the subscribers are not being exported. Support team advised that exporting doesn't always work as expected (bangs head at MC once again). You can query the data using SQL then export from the data extension and shouldn't have any issues

Comment: Just an update. Finally found the cause of this and got it corrected from support. was an issue with MC where part of the subscriber keys were not actually registered correctly in the system despite being counted/visible. 
This meant that we could see them in subscriber preview (email studio) but when actually displaying the preview we would get an error. 
I suggest you bang on at MC Support about this as it may be the same error.