# Export all contacts with automation issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-export, automation, automationstudio

I want to export all subscribers to extract the "status" column on every subscriber. I want to automate the steps as in [this](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/subscribers_for_interactive_marketing_hub/exporting_on_status/) official documentation. I know how i do it manually but it needs to be automated and scheduled. I've checked similar questions like [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/179913/export-all-subscribers) but no luck on getting answers.

From what I understand - I need to create a data extract activity? When im in the first properties step I have nothing to choose in the roll down list of "Extract Type". Is it because I missed something or am I in the wrong automation activity?

Are there other easier ways to perform this?

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions on how to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Tracking Extract**](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/) is the type you need choose.  From there, you have option to **Extract Subscribers.**

Be sure and check the **Include All Subscribers** option otherwise you'll get only Subscribers who've had activity in the date range you've specified.

Note that you need to have Extract types enabled to have the option available, if not you need to contact your SFMC representative or partner support to have it enabled (as per this [documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/use_a_data_extract_activity/extract_types_reference/))

Comment: Thanks for the guidance! Since nothing appears in the roll down list I needed to contact my MC representative to activate it according to the documentation.

Comment: Yep. It's a quick enable for support.